# Remove or change color of mid section of tmux status bar?

Tags: terminal, tmux

I'm currently trying to configure my zsh+tmux setup, and I have a problem with configuring the mid section of the tmux status bar.

Is there any way to configure this? I would preferably remove it, but I found one answer which said that the only way was to change the code and compile a new version (which I don't want to).

But is there a way to change the text color or change the content of the mid section (`0:zsh*` highlited with the red circle)? Using tmux 2.5.

See screnshot below.

[image: Screenshot of Terminal.app + tmux]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer to this. The item can't be removed, but you can change the text color. So I changed the text color to the same as the background, so it's invisible.

`set-window-option -g window-status-current-fg black`

[image]